# SSIS For Loop Container equivalent in Talend Open Studio

Tags: for-loop, containers, talend

I have a talend mapping which needs to be executed based on a ID. I want to pass the ID as a parameter. The mapping should execute for one ID at an time. I want to loop the execution for each ID one after the other. This can be achieved in SSIS using the For Loop Container. Can anyone help me finding out the equivalent for the same in Talend Open Studio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So this isn't an SSIS question it's a Talend question.

Comment: Yes it is a Talend Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analogue tForeach component, and set the ID's values inside it. After that, you should connect the iterate output and reference the current value with the variable `((String)globalMap.get("tForeach_1_CURRENT_VALUE"))` where the `tForeach_1` is the name of your tForeach component.

[image]

[image]

And set the Query to something like:

```
"select id, name  from employee
where id="+((String)globalMap.get("tForeach_1_CURRENT_VALUE"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take just the Id part of your input and then link that to the main part of your current job with an `Iterate` link via a `tFlowToIterate` component it should automatically do this. You can access the value from the GlobalMap using something along the lines of `((String) GlobalMap.get("row1.Id"))`.